# Kudan AR with Unity: customized marker is detected but the augmented model did not appear

Tags: unity-game-engine, kudan, android-augmented-reality

I am trying to modify the Kudan AR tutorial for android which I got it from [here](https://www.ourtechart.com/augmented-reality/tutorial/kudan-slam-technique-pokemon-go/).
Everything works fine and now I am trying to change to my own marker. I have tested with the windows sample pictures like [the Tulips](https://i.stack.imgur.com/9s8UA.jpg) and it works well too. But when I change to my own pictures, the 3D models just did not appear while the marker is detected already.

I have used the kudan AR toolkit to generated the .KARMarker file and added into the DemoMarker function. I have changed the expected Id in the Marker Transform Driver as well, actually I have done all the neccessary steps. When I was testing on my android phone, it shows that the marker is detected, but nothing shows up.

I have searched through the whole internet, one more infomation I got was that it may caused by the scale of the 3D object which means it may be too small comparing to the marker size, so it may have appeared but we just can't see. Then I did changed the size of the model and the size of the marker to ensure that it isn't too big or too small, but after all these, I still can't see the augmented object.

Could anyone please help, I really have no idea where went wrong, why the sample pictures works well but my own pictures won't, is it the pixel problem? I understand what makes a good marker but anyway my marker is being detected so doesn't it mean that my marker is actually qualified? any input would be really appreciated.

Comment: If the marker has been successfully loaded into the tracker and has been detected, then the only reasons an object wouldn't show up is because either the expected ID field is incorrect, so it doesn't make a match in the transform driver and make the object visible, or it's that the object is too small, in which case you have to scale it wayyy up (to at least 100, if not more). The expected ID field is case sensitive, so if there's a capital letter that should or shouldn't be there, that might be the cause.